# Ruby on Rails has_many :through in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have searched and searched and found only partial solutions to my current question.

The thing is, I'd like to know if it is possible to use has_many :through along with a polymorphic association in Ruby on Rails.

I have a system where `students` can create `travel plans` (that can belong to many `students`) and `refund claims` (that can belong to only one `student`) for their projects. In this system, both `admin users` and `students` are able to comment on the plans and claims.

My associations are:

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :travel_plans
   has_many :refund_claims
   has_many :comments, through: :travel_plans
   has_many :comments, through: :refund_claims
end

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :comments
end

class TravelPlan < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_and_belongs_to_many :students
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class RefundClaim < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :student
   has_many :comments, as: :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :commentable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**My questions are:**

Is it correct to associate `comments` twice in the `Student` model?

I don't want the `AdminUsers` to have `travel plans` and `refund claims`, how can I identify their `comments` as being made on a `travel plan` or on a `refund claim`?

Would there be a better approach?

Thanks a lot in advance for everyone!

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to add an polymorphic `author` attribute to the `Comment` model. Than you just need `has_many :comments, as: :author` to the `Student` and `AdminUser` model.

If this is a new application and you are starting on the green field you might want to rethink your models a bit and add a `Role` and a `User` model. `Student` would than be a `role` of `user` as would `AdminUser` be.

Comment: Hi wintermeyer, thanks for the input! Yes, I'm starting from scratch and planning thoroughly all the associations beforehand. I like this idea of creating a `Role` and a `User` model, then the `Role` `belongs_to :user` and the `User` `has_one :role`, correct? But I would still need to identify somehow if the comment was made in the `travel_plan` or in the `refund_claim`... Or am I missing something?

Comment: I think I have an answer for what I just asked you: I have to keep the polymorphic association in the `Comment` model and guarantee that the `User` `has_many :comments`, then I can track the comment type (`travel_plan` or `refund_claim`) and id. Finally, I think I don't need to use `through:` in the `User` model. Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: Correct. BTW: Please check (green checkmark) the answer you prefer.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/activerecord_chapter.html for more examples.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I'll go on with this data model!

Comment: Hey wintermeyer, I've been wondering... Do I really need a `Role` model? As each `user` `has_one :role` and the `role` `belongs_to :user` I could eliminate the `Role` model and just add a `role` column to the `user` database! :)

Comment: Because a given `user` can have many `roles` you need a third table which you can you for a `has_many ... through:` construct. BTW: Forget about `has_one`. Please read http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/4.0/activerecord_chapter.html

Comment: That's true, in that case I would need to define a `has_many :roles` association to the `user`. But in my case the system is simple and each `user` will have only one role, either admin OR student. Oh, and nice reference guide, by the way!

Answer (score 0):

> Is it correct to associate comments twice in the Student model?

No, not really. If you have duplicate association name, you can only use one of them. If you want to use both, you have to name them differently.

Comment: Hi Marek, thanks for your input! Does it mean that I would have to have maybe two `comments` models, let's say one is named `travel_comments` and the other one named `refund_comments`? Is this the only way really?

Comment: No, you can define `travel_comments` and `refund_comments` associations and specify `model_name` and `foreign_key` options, if I remember correctly.

Comment: This definition would be done in the `Student` model?